# Batch move files to folders. Folders are named based off of the filename

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Trying to find a bat that can do this but no luck. With my very limited knowledge of batch coding I have no idea where to begin editing similar existing code.

I have files in a folder as seen below:

```
    \\NAS\ART\1234.pdf
    \\NAS\ART\1235.ai
    \\NAS\ART\1236.eps
```

I want to move these files to another folder on a server where the folder structure is as follows:

```
\\NAS\Art\1234\Original\1234.pdf
\\NAS\Art\1235\Original\1235.ai
\\NAS\Art\1236\Original\1236.eps
```

It would place the file into the original folder of the filenames folder. Sorry if that is confusing.

I have found this which is close to what i want but minus the removal of characters.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.xml" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=_-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*%%b*" '
  ) DO (
   ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Your example files show different extensions but your code only lists `*.xml` files? To much for loops, you need only one. And use the for meta variable modifiers `%%~na` for the name, `%%~dpa`for drive and path etc. See https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html and https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this batch file to move all non-hidden files in `\\NAS\ART\` to the suitable subdirectories created before if not already existing with overwriting a file with same name in target directory.

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("\\NAS\ART\*") do (
    if not "%%I" == "%~f0" (
        md "%%~dpnI\Original" 2>nul
        move /Y "%%I" "%%~dpnI\Original\"
    )
)
```

The **IF** condition avoids moving the batch file on being stored also in directory `\\NAS\ART\` and can be removed if that is surely never the case.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` used to suppress the error message output by command **MD** to handle **STDERR** on directory to create already existing by redirecting this error message to device **NUL**.